# VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [val2] in u'None'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I was getting a `VariableDoesNotExist` error with the following snippet when `obj1.page` is `None`.

```
{{ obj1.val1|default:obj1.page.val2 }}
```

Normally Django templates don't care about attribute accesses on `None` values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django only cares about attribute lookups on `None` values inside the `default` template filter. I got around it using:

```
{% with obj1.page.val2 as val2 %}
{{ obj1.val1|default:val2 }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Note to future googlers: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13167 explains that this bug is not expected to ever be fixed, because they think it will introduce more problems than it fixes. So expect this workaround to be useful for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @CoreDumpError It looks like it's been reopened: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28172 but it's marked as "Someday/Maybe"

Answer (score 0):

VariableDoesNotExist bcoz it's not created in the session...so to create

> views.py(in get method)

`Variable_Name = request.session.get('Variable_Name') if not Variable_Name: request.session.Variable_Name = {}` #Here we create a dictionary

Comment: refer this link